# Animate LI into div

Tags: css, html-lists, css-transitions

I jave just created a Twitter widget for my website and I want to fade in and out the last 5 or more tweets at set intervals using css3 I have set my div to be 60% width with a height of 90px same as my UL and LI as shown below...

```
div#twitterwidget {
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 90px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #EC9A20;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
div#twitterwidget ul {
    list-style:none; 
    height:90px; 
    overflow:hidden
}
div#twitterwidget ul li {
    height:90px
}
```

All I want to achieve is is load up the the next tweet from the bottom using css3 animations! 
Many thanks for your help
Phillip Dews

As Requested here is my HTML

```
<div id="twitterwidget"><script src="js/twitterWidget.js"></script>
<script>
twitterFetcher.fetch('347858782015086592', '', 5, true, false, true, '', false, handleTweets);

function handleTweets(tweets){
    var x = tweets.length;
    var n = 0;
    var element = document.getElementById('twitterwidget');
    var html = '<ul>';
    while(n < x) {
      html += '<li>' + tweets[n] + '</li>';
      n++;
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    element.innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your html, thanks

Comment: sure thing will add above

Comment: It will better to have a jsfiddle for your code.

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: think i got this right http://jsfiddle.net/RThdu/

Comment: Nope, this is right : http://jsfiddle.net/RThdu/2/ :)

Comment: "All I want to achieve is is load up the the next tweet from the bottom using css3 animations". I think you should precise this : when, how... Do you want a continugous scrolling, etc...

Comment: Cheers all I want to have is that each tweet fade in after say 5 seconnds using css3 animation

Comment: Do you have to use CSS3 or could you use jQuery to animate this ? I think this would be far easier in that case.

Comment: Ideally I would prefer CSS but if JS is easier then sure! Many thanks for your help Brewal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I think it would be far easier to use javascript (here with jQuery) to animate your widget. I am not sure of you exaclty want, but this is the idea :

```
function animateWidget() {
    li = $('div#twitterwidget>ul>li:first');
    li.slideUp(1000, function(){
        li.clone().appendTo('div#twitterwidget>ul').show();
        li.remove();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(animateWidget,1000);
});
```

What is done here is :

- run the animation every 1s
- animate the first tweet with `slideUp`
- when the animation is done, put the tweet in the end of the list

See the **[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RThdu/3/)**